# index out of range when working with slices

Tags: go, range, slice, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to convert an old version jsonline into a new one (with a different structure).

Now the old file has the following structure

```
{"user": "myname", "uuid": "1242315425", "data": {"Niveau1": ["AUTRE", "RC"], "Niveau2": ["RA06"], "Niveau3": ["RA06_01"]}}
```

however, Niveau2 and Niveau3 are not always present and the length of the lists is not always the same.

The new file has a more complicated structure

```
{"user": "myname", "uuid": "1242315425","annotation":{"classifications":{"Niveau1":{"labels":[{"value":"AUTRE"}, {"value":"RC"}]}, "Niveau2": {"labels": [{"value":"RA06"}], "Niveau3": {"labels": [{"value":"RA06_01"}]}}}}
```

What I have done so far is (after parsing the files in appropriate structures) the following function

```golang
func convert(oldAnnots []AnnotV1) (newAnnots []AnnotV2) {
    for _, element := range oldAnnots {
            var newAnnot AnnotV2

            newAnnot.User = element.User
            newAnnot.Uuid = element.Uuid
            
            
            if element.Data.Niveau1 != nil {
                for i, annot1 := range element.Data.Niveau1 {
                    newAnnot.Annotation.Classif.Niveau1.Labels[i].Value = annot1
                }
          }
            if element.Data.Niveau2 != nil {
                for j, annot2 := range element.Data.Niveau2 {
                    newAnnot.Annotation.Classif.Niveau2.Labels[j].Value = annot2
                }
          }
            if element.Data.Niveau3 != nil {
                for k, annot3 := range element.Data.Niveau3 {
                    newAnnot.Annotation.Classif.Niveau3.Labels[k].Value = annot3
                }
          }
            newAnnots = append(newAnnots, newAnnot)
    }
    return
}
```

However, I got the error saying the index [0] is out of range for my slice.

```sh
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
```

Definitions of the two structures are the following

```golang
type AnnotV1 struct {
    Uuid string `json:"uuid"`
    Data struct {
        Niveau1 []string `json:"Niveau1"`
        Niveau2 []string `json:"Niveau2"`
        Niveau3 []string `json:"Niveau3"`
    } `json:"data"`
    User string `json:"user"`
}
```

and

```golang
type AnnotV2 struct {
    Uuid string `json:"uuid"`
    Annotation struct {
        Classif struct {
            Niveau1 struct {
                Labels []struct {
                    Value string `json:value`
                } `json:"labels"`
            }
            Niveau2 struct {
                Labels []struct {
                    Value string `json:value`
                } `json:"labels"`
            }
            Niveau3 struct {
                Labels []struct {
                    Value string `json:value`
                } `json:"labels"`
            }
        } `json:"classifications"`
    } `json:"annotation"`
    User string `json:"user"`
}
```

Comment: So, what line of code that panic happens on? The runtme tells you that. It also tells you the complete call chain led to that panic. What do you gather from those pieces of information?

Comment: Well, I thought I handled this by `if element.Data.NiveauX != nil`. In any case this is not causing the issue directly (since the error is already in Niveau1. If I add a print of annot1 it prints correctly, but I do not manage to do the assignment `newAnnot.Annotation.Classif.Niveau1.Labels[i].Value = annot1`

Comment: You need to pre-allocate the `Labels` slice to the same length as the old `Niveau` slice to be able to index into it. Or you need to use append. In both cases you should probably declare a named `Label` type to make it easier to do.

Comment: Please note that checking a slice for `!= nil` may be not enough: a declaration `s := []int{}` produces a non-`nil` slice with zero elements (`len(s) == 0`).

Comment: Thank you. I have done this, by creating another struct `Label` and make([]Labels, len(NiveauX)) but I got errors anyway (type non-literal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```golang
type Label struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

type AnnotV2 struct {
    Uuid string `json:"uuid"`
    Annotation struct {
        Classif struct {
            Niveau1 struct {
                Labels []Label `json:"labels"`
            }
            Niveau2 struct {
                Labels []Label `json:"labels"`
            }
            Niveau3 struct {
                Labels []Label `json:"labels"`
            }
        } `json:"classifications"`
    } `json:"annotation"`
    User string `json:"user"`
}
```

pre-allocate the slice

```golang
if element.Data.Niveau2 != nil {
    newAnnot.Annotation.Classif.Niveau2.Labels = make([]Label, len(element.Data.Niveau2))
    for j, annot2 := range element.Data.Niveau2 {
        newAnnot.Annotation.Classif.Niveau2.Labels[j].Value = annot2
    }
}
```

or use append

```golang
if element.Data.Niveau2 != nil {
    for _, annot2 := range element.Data.Niveau2 {
        newAnnot.Annotation.Classif.Niveau2.Labels = append(newAnnot.Annotation.Classif.Niveau2.Labels, Label{annot2})
    }
}
```